# Are VAE useful for Maximum-Likelihood estimation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, variational-bayes, approximate-inference

In the ["Auto-encoding Variation Bayes" Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf) they state under "2.1 Problem Scenarios" that the VAE is a solution to:

"1. Efficient approximate ML or MAP estimation for the parameters $\theta$".

I am wondering if that makes sense. If one would just want to do an ML-Estimate for $\theta$ one would not need the recognition model/decoder $q_\phi$, right? One could just use the reparametrization trick on the model/encoder network $g_\theta$, which adds Gaussian noise on its last layer:

$$p_\theta(x) = E_{\epsilon}\left[~ \mathcal{N}\left(x ~|~ \mu(g^1_\theta(\epsilon)), \sigma(g^2_\theta(\epsilon)\right) ~\right]$$

where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are outputs of a neural network. This would basically reduce to doing least squares on a generator network to fit the samples.

The VAE now basically also will do this but on top train the approximate posterior over $z$. Am I right in understanding, that this approximate posterior is the actual subject of interest, since otherwise just doing the above least squauares approach would be much simpler?

Answer (score 1):

The expectation you wrote can't be computed efficiently and with an acceptable degree of accuracy -- about 3 paragraphs above where you quote, the authors describe this:

> Intractability: the case where the integral of the marginal likelihood
> $p_\theta(x) = \int p_\theta(z) p_\theta(x|z) dz$ is intractable (so we cannot evaluate or
> differentiate the marginal likelihood) ... These
> intractabilities are quite common and appear in cases of moderately
> complicated likelihood functions pθ(x|z), e.g. a neural network with a
> nonlinear hidden layer

Comment: Yes but the recognition model does not change this problem, does it? Now you have to evaluate and differentiate $$E_{q_\phi(z)}[\log p_\theta (x^{(i)} |  z)]$$ later. This is done by the reparam. trick. Why not do the same here? I.e. choose $p_\theta(z)$ s.t. you can use the reparametrization trick and evaluate/differentiate the marginal likelihood $$p_\theta(x) = E_{p_\theta(z)}[\log p_\theta (x^{(i)} |  z)].$$

Comment: the recognition model doesn't make things tractable either, the use of a variational lower bound on the likelihood does.

Comment: I see, we are now evaluating/differentiating something of the form $E_{q_\phi}[\log p(x | z)]$ instead of $E_{p_\theta}[p(x|z)]$. How does the logarithm make this tractable?